# Insert with 1 known value and 2 Selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have

```
insert into Messages (Content, Sender, Reciever) values (?) SELECT 
(SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) AS Sender,
(SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) AS Reciever;
```

I have the content to insert into Content but I need to do a Select to get what to insert into Sender and Reciever (yes I know this is spelled wrong). How do I combine these 2?

Comment: So, what problem are you having?

Comment: I think my issue is that the "values (?)" is wrong? I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) AS Sender, (SELECT use' at line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
insert into Messages(Content, Sender, Reciever)
    SELECT ?,
           (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) AS Sender,
           (SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE Username=?) AS Reciever;
```

You don't need the `values` statement.  `insert . . . select` is fine.